# problem with decimate in scipy 0.18

Tags: discrete-signals, scipy

I use `scipy.signal.decimate`  to downsample a large spectroscopic data-set.
This has worked superbly so far.

```
yy = decimate(data.row(i).buffer, n2, ftype = "fir")
```

I used successively to downsample the spectrum to several lower resolutions.

When I moved from scipy 0.17 to 0.18 (actually 0.18.1) during of a python3 port, a problem appeared.
The first downsampling works, on all the rows; but the next one crashes with the following message:

```
File "..../lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/signal/signaltools.py", line 3049, in decimate
raise TypeError("q must be an integer")
TypeError: q must be an integer
```

I looked to the code, but with no avail. I also tried the new `zero_phase=True` argument, but did not help. Needless to say that my `n2` argument above IS an integer, the second time as well as the first time!

Any pointers ?

Comment: Have you tried `int(n2)` in function call? Remember that Python3 might yield floats in places where they were integers before (the division operation has changed). Just in case, what is the output of `print(type(n2))`?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the bug !
`n2` is indeed a integer in my case, but its not an `int()`

`print(type(n2))` gives:   `<class 'numpy.int64'>`   !!!

In the previous version of scipy, it was already a `numpy.int64` but it was working correctly.

Maybe a test slightly too stringent...

Thanks for helping everyone.

Comment: Actually it's been this way since the function was created 8 years ago :)  So it must be something in your code.  Anyway, I made a change to make it less strict, so it will accept `int(2)`, `2.0`, `numpy.array(2)`, `Fraction(2)`, etc.  I'm fixing the same issue in other functions and then will submit the pull request.  :D

Comment: This is inside a big loop in a big application. The `n2` parameters comes from another scipy/numpy computation, which might have changed.
If there is any interest, I might investigate.

Comment: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/7351

Answer (score 0):

The input `n2` must be an actual integer (like `3`), not a float with integer value (like `3.0`).  Replace `n2` with `int(n2)` in the function call:

```
yy = decimate(data.row(i).buffer, int(n2), ftype = "fir")
```

`signaltools.py` contains:

```
def decimate(x, q, n=None, ftype='iir', axis=-1, zero_phase=None):
    ...
    if not isinstance(q, int):
        raise TypeError("q must be an integer")

    if n is not None and not isinstance(n, int):
        raise TypeError("n must be an integer")
```

Probably because it's used in a slice and NumPy slices won't accept non-integers anymore.

(I would think the function should be more forgiving and check for `int(q) == q` instead, and then convert to `int` internally if needed for slicing.  I'll try to change it if I have time.)